# Zend Ajax post to action

Tags: jquery, post

I have a select dropdown with options:

```html
<select id="select_privilege_section" name="select_privilege_section" onchange="">
    <option value="pages">Pages</option> 
    <option value="forms">Forms</option> 
    <option value="roles">Roles</option> 
    <option value="cos">Change of Status</option>
</select>
```

I need to be able to send via ajax the option selected on change, to a specific action in a controller to be retrieved there in order to select which form related to the option it has to be displayed:

```js
var input =  $(this).val();

$.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url: location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/role/privilege/format/html',
    data: {"form": input},
    success: function(data) {
    console.log("Success!!");   
  } 
});
```

But I am not being able to get the `$_POST['form'];` there

Any idea why?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The url you are posting to is wrong if I'm not mistaken. Try debugging it and check it is a valid url.